# Как правильно разделить класс?

Tags: c++, ооп

Я делаю игру на C++ с сюжетом, сюжет помещаю в класс как отдельный метод по главам.

Так получается, что глава выходит по 300-400 строк, стоит ли разделить этот класс на несколько файлов?

Имеется в виду будет Story.h и Story.Chapter1.cpp, Story.Chapter2.cpp

Будет ли это приниматься за норму?

Или лучше стоит писать всё в одном файле?

Comment: Как вам удобнее, так и делайте. Тут нет единой практики или правил.

Comment: Методы по 300-400 строк уже нехорошо. Разделение на отдельные файлы поможет слабо.

Comment: Chorkov, Там одни cout, для вывода сюжета, как тогда их раскидать?

Comment: Если так, то текст хранить во внешнем хранилище (txt, xml, и т.п.). Старайтесь не смешивать ассеты/данные и код.